# Variable scope if else statement

Tags: ios, variables, if-statement

This may sound not very smart but I'm having little difficulties in getting to make this method work. I want to use the interstitialad variable to store the time when it is called in first condition. And then when the callcount >=2 I want to use the same value from previous. Can someone give me ideas?

```
    -(void)timestamp{

       long now = [[NSDate date]timeIntervalSince1970]/1000;
        long interstitialad = 0.00;
        long finalad;

       if(Callcount ==1){
        interstitialad = [[NSDate date]timeIntervalSince1970]/1000;

       }

     else if (Callcount >= 2 && now - interstitialad >= 200){

     [self displayInterstitial];

     }
```

Comment: Why are you using `long` with decimal places? Use `double` or `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Make it an instance variable of the class this code is in and use the same object of that class to handle all the `timestamp` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared inside an if statement (or an else statement) go out of scope when the statement ends.  You will have to declare the variable before the if/else statement for its value to be persistent between statements.  Note that some languages treat bonded if/else statements as the same statement and others do not.

Comment: But the timestamp I want to store is when the first condition is met. And when the second condition is met I want to use the same value.

Comment: Declaring the variable outside of the if statement will cause its value to be preserved over the statement.  I'm not sure if you call that in a loop or somewhere else, but as long as you don't reassign it and its value doesn't go out of scope, it will hold the value from the last statement that assigned it.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to understand that in the if else only one of them will be accessed every time you call timestamp. If you are hoping to do both checks in one run get rid of the else keyword.

If all you want to do is keep the value of interstitialad variable through out the class, simply convert it to an instance variable by moving it out of the method, declaring it in your interface and keeping a reference to it with it's properties set correctly.

Comment: @A Salcedo Thank you. Your explanation seems pretty straightforward.